# Symfony Doctrine: Adding new new Annotation namespaces to an existing reader

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

I have implemented my own `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber` that subscribes to "onFlush" events and compares the EntityChangeSet to a hard coded list of class properties (like `User->Name` and `Event->Date`) and logs the change if necessary.

As property names of the other classes might change, I'd much rather prefer to annotate these properties with a custom made `@Loggable`.

I have built the Annotation class "Loggable", added `use MyNamespace\Annotations\Loggable;` to the `User` and `Event` classes and have a method in my EventSubscriber that creates a `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader` and uses its `getPropertyAnnotation($property, 'Loggable')` to check for a non-null value.

## Now to the problem

As one could expect (or not), this particular reader throws

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Id" in property MyNamespace\Entities\User::$id was never imported.
```

and is not aware of any other ORM-annotations that the reader in my  `EntityManager` knows about.

Do I actually have to add `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` to **every** Entity class and prefix **every** ORM-annotation with `ORM\` *just* to please this newly created reader or is there a way to reuse the reader in my `EntityManager` (a `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader` by default, if I understood correctly?)

I did my research and read through most of the answers related to Doctrine and Annotations, but I seem to be missing some conceptual understanding. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: mh, I always import (`use`) the annotations that I use. I suppose that would be the clean way.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the **AnnotationReader** class use **getClassAnnotations** and **getClassAnnotation** (which use **getClassAnnotations** in fact).

**getClassAnnotations:**

```
public function getClassAnnotations(ReflectionClass $class)
{
    $this->parser->setTarget(Target::TARGET_CLASS);
    $this->parser->setImports($this->getClassImports($class));
    $this->parser->setIgnoredAnnotationNames($this->getIgnoredAnnotationNames($class));
    $this->parser->setIgnoredAnnotationNamespaces(self::$globalIgnoredNamespaces);

    return $this->parser->parse($class->getDocComment(), 'class ' . $class->getName());
}
```

**getClassAnnotation:**

```
public function getClassAnnotation(ReflectionClass $class, $annotationName)
{
    $annotations = $this->getClassAnnotations($class);

    foreach ($annotations as $annotation) {
        if ($annotation instanceof $annotationName) {
            return $annotation;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Just take a look at this line:

```
$this->parser->setImports($this->getClassImports($class));
```

The annotation reader collects the **use** statements in order to detect any other annotation that you use.
So, about your question

> Do I actually have to add use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; to every Entity class and prefix every ORM-annotation with ORM\ [...]?

I should answer: yes, you do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you saved me from giving up! 
I posted my solution, even if it's not very beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frank Gamess' explanations I finally managed to wade through the jungle of Doctrine's codebase and find a messy, but working solution, that doesn't involve explicit namespaces for every file.

Instead of using the simpler `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration()` when creating my EntityManager, I went a bit more verbose and performed most of the steps of the configuration myself:

```
// preloading all of Doctrine's Annotation classes
$rc = new \ReflectionClass(Configuration::class);
$dir = dirname($rc->getFileName());

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile($dir . '/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');

// preloading my own classes
$dir = $dir ?? self::BASE_DIR . '/src/Annotations';  // BASE_DIR is my project root directory
// CustomAnnotations.php is built the same way as DoctrineAnnotations.php;
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile($dir . '/CustomAnnotations.php');

$reader = new SimpleAnnotationReader();
$reader->addNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping');
$reader->addNamespace('MyProject\Annotations');

$mapping_driver = new AnnotationDriver($reader, [self::BASE_DIR . '/src/Entities']);

$config = Setup::createConfiguration();
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($mapping_driver);
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);

$EM = EntityManager::create($db_params, $config, new EventManager());

// adding the objects to my ORM-objects for later use
$this->annotation_reader = $reader;
$this->EM = $EM;
```

Now I can use my annotations without any use-statements or FQCN. Maybe not cleaner, but less repetitive.

As this works, I might be able to go on to more urgent things, but if anyone can point out possibilities for refactoring, I'm all ears!